# Creating a custom control/action for a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, powerapp

I am wondering if it is possible to add a custom control/action for files in a document library in SharePoint. For example, when I select a file or click the ellipsis for a file I get the options to preview, share, copy link, download ,etc... I want to know if it's possible to create my own custom option for this which will trigger a ms flow and pass the file properties to ms flow?
To be more specific, I already have a ms flow that automatically picks up files when they are uploaded to sharepoint and copies these files to a different environment. I just need to see if I am able to implement a custom option, when you click that option it will trigger the flow for that file and copy the file to the different environment or if it is even possible to add  custom options for files in a document library.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Omi in a hellcat,

@Murilo Santana has provided a good solution. you may also have a look [SPFx ListView Command Set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api#debug-your-listview-command-set) Extension:

[image]

It can trigger an HTTP flow:

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/download-sharepoint-list-item-pdf-using-microsoft-flow-maniyani/

BR

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a flow with the "For a selected file" trigger.

That trigger allows you to select a file in a library to initiate a flow from there - you can also set input options when running the flow. Inside the flow you will then be able to use any other actions you'd like.

[image]

You will see this option on SharePoint

[image]